# Why is there no central resource for fixing installations

Tags: discussion, new-users

I have been trying to fix my Kubuntu 14.04 installation for the past two days now. I have found that there is generally very little self-contained help/guides/tutorials available. While there is an abundance of posts about various methods for fixing installations, none of them walk you through the **entire** process of fixing the installation.

I understand that there is simply too many different variables that could go wrong to cover every single possible error, but (I am assuming) new Linux users are more prone to mucking up their system. I have found that assembling all the available information about mounting discs, using `chroot`, etc. is simply too overwhelming and very frustrating.

As a counterexample: there are dozens of guides/tutorials available for installing a Linux systems.

So, to recap, why are there hardly any self-contained guides for repairing Ubuntu/Linux installations?

Answer (score 9):

I don't understand how you can say...

> I understand that there is simply too many different variables that could go wrong to cover every single possible error

... And still expect a self-contained guide that covers everything.

An unbootable Ubuntu install can be caused by so many different things, each with very different recovery paths. Putting all of these on one page seems likely to just encourage somebody to try them all. That isn't safe. The person needs to work out what they did.

And that's before you consider that the Stack Exchange model here prefers distinct issues and solutions rather than arbitrary amalgamations. If you want to write a resource for every eventuality, please feel free to [write a Wiki page on that](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/). We're all on the same team.

Comment: I see that I might not have made my point very clear: What I meant was that guides generally focus on reinstalling GRUB, i.e. guides are very monotonous when it comes to what suggestions are made to fix broken installations. There is, for example, not one guide/tutorial on how to reinstall anything but Ubuntu (Kubuntu, Xubuntu,etc.).  I would at least like to see some sort of list of options that can be tried to fix a broken installation.

Comment: It depends on how the installation's broken -- there are many different issues that could be happening, depending on OS version, hardware, drivers, etc. As @Oli said, feel free to compile your own guide from questions and answers here on AskUbuntu, if you want a comprehensive document. Otherwise, searching for the specific issue/error seems to work well for most people

Answer (score 0):

Like Oli said, on Stack Exchange you look for one answer to one problem and then move on to the next. If problems are related or very complex, one answer should link to the next in the chain especially if it already exists. That's the source for much of the frustration: too many people not using the site appropriately by asking questions that have already been answered and answerers that don't look at good existing answers to link to them.